# Dynamic Layout iOS with Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

This might be a simple question -- I'm new to iOS Development.

I have a homepage with a Collection View with four cells that take up the whole screen (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right) in portrait mode. In landscape mode, I want all four cells to be side by side in a row.

Is Collection View the right layout to use? Should I use Autoresizing to do this, or do I have to use some other layout constraints?

Thank you!

Comment: I would put the first two views in a horizontal stack view and the second two views in another horizontal stack view, then put both stack views in an outer stack view that switches between horizontal and vertical for landscape/portrait

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is the right layout to use.
you can use the following for making layout

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(4 - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(4))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Following way you can use it inside your view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@objc(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(4 - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(4))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
}
```

Comment: Where should this function be?

Comment: In your view controller, i edited the answer kindly check

Answer (score 0):

it should be a merge beetween UIStackView and [Sizeclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html)

[image: you will need to use 3 stackviews]

the stackviews have to have *fill equaly distribution*.

[image]

the selected stackview has to have *axis vertical* by default, but you should add horizontal axis sizeclass *width regular | height any*